# SSE - mismatch between _mm_extract_ps and direct access

Tags: c++, sse

The following piece of code:

```
__m128 var1;
float *a = (float*)malloc(50*sizeof(float));
float *ptr = a;

//Initialise a with some values
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    *(a+i) = i; 

//print those values
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i+=4,ptr+=4) 
{
    var1 = _mm_loadu_ps(ptr);
    cout<<(*ptr)<<" "<<var1[0]<<" "<<_mm_extract_ps(var1, 0)<<endl;
    cout<<(*ptr+1)<<" "<<var1[1]<<" "<<_mm_extract_ps(var1, 1)<<endl;
    cout<<(*ptr+2)<<" "<<var1[2]<<" "<<_mm_extract_ps(var1, 2)<<endl;
    cout<<(*ptr+3)<<" "<<var1[3]<<" "<<_mm_extract_ps(var1, 3)<<endl;
}
```

returns this output:

`0 0 0
1 1 1065353216
2 2 1073741824
3 3 1077936128
4 4 1082130432
5 5 1084227584
6 6 1086324736
7 7 1088421888
8 8 1090519040
9 9 1091567616
10 10 1092616192
11 11 1093664768
12 12 1094713344
13 13 1095761920
14 14 1096810496
15 15 1097859072
16 16 1098907648
17 17 1099431936
18 18 1099956224
19 19 1100480512
20 20 1101004800
21 21 1101529088
22 22 1102053376
23 23 1102577664
24 24 1103101952
25 25 1103626240
26 26 1104150528
27 27 1104674816
28 28 1105199104
29 29 1105723392
30 30 1106247680
31 31 1106771968
32 32 1107296256
33 33 1107558400
34 34 1107820544
35 35 1108082688
36 36 1108344832
37 37 1108606976
38 38 1108869120
39 39 1109131264
40 40 1109393408
41 41 1109655552
42 42 1109917696
43 43 1110179840
44 44 1110441984
45 45 1110704128
46 46 1110966272
47 47 1111228416
48 48 1111490560
49 49 1111752704
1.45875e-42 1.45875e-42 1041
0 0 0`

My questions is: Isn't `_mm_extract_ps` the right way of accessing the contents of an `__m128` variable? Why does it print values that dont match the actual value, whereas `var[0]` prints the correct values. As far as I know, accessing the fields of an `__m128` variable using `var[0]` is incorrect and may lead to problems. What exactly is the right approach, at times when I need to debug my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of `a` is pointer to float, when you write float == 1.0f, into memory, its representation in hex is 0x3F800000, decimal value is 1 065 353 216, so printed value is valid, `_mm_extract_ps` returns int, and cout prints it.  Hex representation of 2.0f is 0x40000000, in decimal 1 073 741 824. You printed hex representation of float using decimal value.

Comment: Wow, didn't think of that. Another question. Accessing the variables as var[0] is fine as long as I am checking the correctness of the values in the code right?

Comment: @Blue hmm, i don't understand your question. What do you mean ? When are you checking the correctness of values ? Data was filled, loaded into __m128 and just printed.

Comment: What I mean is to check if the correct values are loaded/obtained after calculation. I am matching my c++ code to my sse optimised c++ code to check if all arrays match in both outputs. This was a sample program I wrote to explain the confusion I had.